# Communication between Linux programs

Tags: c, unix, posix, ipc

how would I implement communication between Linux programs written in C? Specifically, I want the following:

My program can run in multiple instances. Upon startup, I want that my program detects all other instances of my program that are already running and then it should be able to send a text string to them. On the other hand, I also want that the instances that are already running get notified that a new instance has been started and they should also be able to send a text string to the new instance.

Could someone point me to some APIs which could be used to implement such a software design on Linux? On Windows, I can simply enumerate over all windows, check their class names to find out all instances of my program, and then register a custom message with the system that I can use to send data to them. But how would I do this on Linux?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: I like the use of the word "simply" in your third paragraph. ;-)

Comment: I think "simply" is OP's word for "fragilely". :-)

Comment: Well, I think simply (again!) using EnumWindows() and comparing the class names is as simple as it can get. The named pipe thingy sounds much more complicated in my ears but that's surely a matter of taste ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start with [named pipes](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/named_pipes.html)

Comment: But what happens when the user closes the instance that acts as the pipe server? Then there are only clients left!

Comment: @AndreasFalkenhahn There is no pipe server. A named pipe is an actual directory entry of type `fifo` on the filesystem (as opposed to block device, file, directory, etc; hence the `mkfifo` command). To that effect, /var/${myapp}/ipcpipe could be a statically referenced location.

Comment: All the servers/clients can open the pipe in read or write, the pipe exists at the OS level. You can even create it independant of the program with mkfifo

Comment: Ok, so named pipes aren't deleted when the process terminates. But when do they get deleted? When the system is rebooted?

Comment: @AndreasFalkenhahn - you can either explicitly delete them when the last client exits, or from the command line or they will be deleted autmatically on restart - whatever works for your app

Comment: One more question: I'd like every instance of my program to get a unique port name. I'll add this port name to a named pipe together with the name of the named pipe for communicating with that instance. So I'll have one named pipe containing all the port names and then one named pipe for every instance of my program for all i/o with it. Now, as instances are started and closed, port names have to be removed from/added to the named pipe that contains the list of port names. Now what happens if two instances try to remove their port names from that list at the very same time?

Comment: This link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of options:

- Named pipes;
- Msg commands (msgget, msgsend);
- Using TCP sockets;
- Using UNIX domain sockets;
- Using a third party broker, like DBus or ActiveMQ;

If it is for a standalone machine, and only one stream of data, I would recommend the option number 1.

Answer (score 2):

- 1st pointer: [The Linux Kernel: IPC Mechanisms](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html)
- 2nd pointer: [Detailed documentation on using shared memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used sockets and multicast for that very purpose. This allows distribution of processes among several computers on the same LAN.